# getting drop-down query script to trigger only when user hovers over a child div

Tags: jquery, slide, drop-down-menu, slidedown

I have the following hover script that handles the sliding down of sub menus in my navigation bar:

```
$j('body').ready(function() {
    $j('.menu-item').hover(function() {
        $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown("slow");
    },
        function() {
            $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp("slow");
        });
});
```

At present the slide down is activated whenever the user hovers over the .menu-item div, as expected.  However, I would only like the slide down to be activated when the user hovers over a child div contained within the .menu-item div, namely .bottom_nav.

HTML is in the form:

```
<li class="menu-item">
<div class="box">
    <div class="top_nav">
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <div class="bottom_nav">
            <div class="left_nav">
            </div>
            <div class="center_nav">
                <a href="http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/news/">news</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right_nav">
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="top_nav">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <div class="bottom_nav">
                    <div class="left_nav">
                    </div>
                    <div class="center_nav">
                        <a href="http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/news/events/">events</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_nav">
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
```

You can see the nav item in action on [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/), specifically on the 'news' item, which has a dropdown for an events page.  You will need to enter the following credentials as the site is under development:

username:guest

password:stackoverflow

Comment: Incidentally, if you'd like us to see your code in action don't hide it behind a log-in, ideally post a *minimal*, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), live-demo that reproduces your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), or similar.

Comment: It's hard to do this with the site I am working on at the moment as I am working on a child theme for a Wordpress theme and there are many different CSS style sheets and overrides.  I will temporarily remove the login instead.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have now managed to get a mockup jsfiddle to reproduce the issue, which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/uVbJp/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted this by adding the following:

```
$j('.sub-menu').hover(function() {
    $j(this).stop().slideDown("fast");
}, function() {
    $j(this).stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is amend your selector to specify that particular `div` and then, within the `hover()` method, navigate back up the DOM to the `.menu-item` element and, therein, find the `.bottom_nav` element to animate:

```
$j('.menu-item .bottom_nav').hover(function() {
    $j(this).closest('.menu-item').find('.sub-menu').slideDown("slow");
},
function() {
    $j(this).closest('.menu-item').find('.sub-menu').slideUp("slow");
});
```

This applies the `hover()` method only to the `.bottom_nav` element(s) found within the `.menu-item` parent.

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).
- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but then I don't get any slide down at all, presumably because the .sub-menu div isn't contained within '.menu-item .bottom_nav' (though it is within .menu-item), so it can't be found.

Comment: Try the updated code; I hadn't unpicked the lack of indenting when I wrote the original answer. =/

Comment: Thanks David, that works for the hover, though this seems to create another issue in that the sub menu is now sliding up when I leave the bottom_nav div, even when I am moving the pointer into the .sub_menu div.  So I need to find a way of keeping the .sub-menu div visible when hovering over it.

Comment: Please show a demo that I can work with, as suggested in my comment to your question.

Comment: I decided to start from scratch with a mock up example, which you can find on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/uVbJp/).  As with the implementation on my site, when moving out of the #bottom div into the #sub_nav menu, the #sub_nav slides up when it needs to stay visible.